# How to post unique records to firebase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to post to firebase and essentially what I want is to post an object into an array and then when I retrieve this array I'll be able to iterate over it and then display it.

```
const postMatchesDataToFirebase = () => {
  console.log(_.uniqueid(), 'id');
  firebase.database().ref('matches/' + uniqueid).set({
    homeTeam: 'Arsenal',
    awayTeam: 'Spurs',
    homeGoals: 4,
    awayGoals: 1
  })
}
```

I am wanting to do something like this but having trouble getting lodash uniqueid to work

currently this posts: `matches/undefined/` then my data

how do I post it in the way I want?

Comment: well that's my question..I don't really care I just want something uniquely generated for me so that each record is stored individually. essentially I'll just be pulling them down and then using them. I thought as I hit submit, it would post a match, with an ID and then store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `push()` method in firebase it will automatic generate unique key for your record. use `set()` or `update()` method to create your own custom keys.

*You can use custom keys by generating timestamp*

```
let uniqueid = "uniqueid_" + Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000));
let person = {  
    "uniqueid": uniqueid,
    //u can form your json data here
};

firebase.database().ref('matches/').set(person).then(function(){
            alert("data sended Successfully..!");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
   function addMatch(){
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  var matchref = ref.child('match');
  var posting = matchref.push();
  posting.set({
   homeTeam: 'Arsenal',
   awayTeam: 'Spurs',
   homeGoals: 4,
   awayGoals: 1
  });
}
```

Which will give you:

```
match
   randomidhere
         homeTeam: Arsenal
         awayTeam: Spurs
         homeGoals: 4
         awayGoals: 1
```